# How to get Google OAuth 2.0 Token via rest request

Tags: rest, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-oauth

I want to use **Firebase Cloud Messaging** for managing notifications in a web application. Currently the configuration of **FCM** is ready for my project, I managed to simulate manually the sending of notifications using the console. But the objective is to achieve this result automatically. that is to say every hour, my system automatically triggers the request for a new token which will be stored in the database and used for sending push notifications.

Using [oauthplayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) I manage to get a token and send my push notifications.

how to achieve it by using REST request and without human intervention ?

I thought of using oauthplayground for the first time and then calling the https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token API to regenerate the token. But I get this error message

> {
>     "error": "unauthorized_client",
>     "error_description": "Unauthorized"
>   }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe your backend server(from where you want to make the FCM calls) some more? Is it a java/node.js backend?

Comment: I use an oracle environment. And by using a PL / SQL block I have the possibility of making REST requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be using a non-google environment, you'll need to download a service account JSON file from your Firebase project. Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#provide-credentials-using-adc) firebase documentation.

Once you do this, you should be able to mint the OAuth 2 access tokens using the service account JSON file and a Google API Client Library for your preferred language as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#use-credentials-to-mint-access-tokens).

The client libraries are available for most of the common languages(java, python,node.js etc). Using one of these libraries is the easiest way to generate and OAuth tokens for FCM.

Comment: I have my JSON service account file.
And finally, I need to use Google API Client Library among the following languages:
Node.js, JAVA or Python.
In this case, I will choose to build a web service which will return my token which I will use in my ORACLE environment.

Comment: yes, please try this and see if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks @Derryl, Im now able to retrive token using java client library by making rest request in Oracle environnement.

Comment: Awesome! :) Happy coding!